# [<__NSCFString 0x7f8392695300> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Terminating app due to uncaught exception

> NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x7f8392695300> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.

getting an exception.. i am trying to display database values to tableview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Dequeue the cell.
    //static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"idCellRecord" forIndexPath:indexPath];

   NSInteger indexOfFirstname = [self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"name"];

    NSInteger indexOfLastname = [self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"fname"];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@ "%@ %@", [[self.arrPeopleInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"name"], [[self.arrPeopleInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"fname"]];
```

Comment: Just check if you have set the outlets properly for tableview to same class, for datasource and delegate as well

Comment: BTW how are you initializing the UITableViewCell?
Just check with breakpoint on NSInteger line if cell is nil

Answer (score 2):

```
[self.arrPeopleInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

Is returning a string, you are then attempting to call '`valueForKey`:' on that and strings do not respond to that selector. Check that the contents of `arrPeopleInfo` are actually dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps:

1) Go to class `xib` file or if its in `storyboard`

2) Right click on `UITableView`, `remove` all earlier `bindings`

3) Add new binding by providing `IBOutlet`, `delegate` and `datasource`.

4) `Clean` `project` and run again.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that your Table View isn't **key-value compliant**, meaning that KVP's (**Key-Value Pairs**) are **unavailable** for that type of object.

Comment: Use **methods** to change values if you can. I don't know the specifics because I don't often work with tables and databases. I'd go with Prince's answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Check your storyboard n clear the warnings. There should be some connection errors or warnings[image: in your case there will be some yellow marks, clear it n see]

in your case there will be some yellow marks, clear it n see. it will work

Comment: this is what i was looking for. great job ;)